# Grouping by date then sum

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following model:

```
public class MonthReport
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public DateTime MonthYear { set; get; }
    public int LateEntry { set; get; }
    public int LeftEarly { set; get; }
    public int TotalAttandence { set; get; }
    public int Great { set; get; }
    public int PersonelId { set; get; }
    public Personel Personel { set; get; }
}
```

Which maps to db with code first.

I want to group, reports by month, and year, then I want to get the sums for that particular month for LateEntry, LeftEarly, and other int values.

I have the following snippet which fails to return correct stuff.

```
    public ActionResult GetReportsGroupedByMonth()
    { 
        var results = _db.MonthReports
                         .GroupBy(
                            x => new
                            {
                                Month = x.MonthYear.Month,
                                Year = x.MonthYear.Year
                            }, 
                            (key, g) => 
                                new ChartModel
                                {
                                    Date = g.Select(v=>v.MonthYear).FirstOrDefault(),
                                    GreatDay = g.Select(e=>e.Great).Sum(),
                                    LateEntry = g.Select(e => e.LateEntry).Sum(),
                                    LeftEarly = g.Select(e => e.LateEntry).Sum(),
                                    TotalAttendance = g.Select(e => e.LateEntry).Sum(),
                                });

        return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

In result set, the values are same.

What s the problem here?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using MS SQL server? There is no aggregate function that would work as `FirstOrDefault`. Also, I'd use `g.Great.Sum()` instead of `g.Select(e => e.Great).Sum()` and such. Have you checked the generated SQL?

Comment: `LeftEarly = g.Select(e => e.LateEntry).Sum(),` should be `LeftEarly = g.Select(e => e.LeftEarly).Sum(),`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just a copy/paste fail.  You selected/summed `e.LateEntry` for 3 properties in your `ChartModel`.

Consider changing

```
new ChartModel
    {
        Date = g.Select(v=>v.MonthYear).FirstOrDefault(),
        GreatDay = g.Select(e=>e.Great).Sum(),
        LateEntry = g.Select(e => e.LateEntry).Sum(),
        LeftEarly = g.Select(e => e.LateEntry).Sum(),
        TotalAttendance = g.Select(e => e.LateEntry).Sum(),
    });
```

to

```
new ChartModel
    {
        Date = g.Select(v=>v.MonthYear).FirstOrDefault(),
        GreatDay = g.Select(e=>e.Great).Sum(),
        LateEntry = g.Select(e => e.LateEntry).Sum(),
        LeftEarly = g.Select(e => e.LeftEarly).Sum(),
        TotalAttendance = g.Select(e => e.TotalAttendance).Sum(),
    });
```

Comment: `I think it's just a copy/paste fail`. If you think so just vote to close as *"This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error."* Why posting an answer.

Comment: Ha, I actually wasn't aware that was an option.  I posted an answer because I think it solves OP's problem and my intent was to help OP.